# SQL ORDER BY route information

Tags: mysql, sql

Ik have a table with route information in random order, like this:

```
from    to      street
----------------------------------
92      91      Lange Poten
100     104     Bagijnestraat
85      79      Korte Poten
91      85      Plein
79      100     Bezuidenhoutseweg
```

I'm trying to find a method to sort it using the route information, where the **to** column of the current row matches with the **from** column of the next row. In the example, the order I want is:

```
from    to      street
----------------------------------
92      91      Lange Poten
91      85      Plein
85      79      Korte Poten
79      100     Bezuidenhoutseweg
100     104     Bagijnestraat
```

A simple ORDER BY on the **from** or **to** column doesn't work because a numerical order isn't the right one. I'm trying to find a method using SQL or Excel.

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ebbb

Comment: There are max like 50 rows per route, so no performance constraints. I'm open for solutions that don't use SQL.

Comment: This is essentially a graph traversal problem. There are numerous resources and how-to's on graphs and their associated algorithms (traversal, search, optimum paths, etc). I found a pretty good one in SQL, it's rather long but it may give you some hints: http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html

Comment: @OttoCoster: Which database is this for?

Comment: @MarkByers It's MySQL, according to the SQL Fiddle he posted - I've added the tag.

Comment: I was using MySQL but I'm not restricted to specific database. The solution in Oracle seems good, so I'm happy to use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This works in oracle

```
select a.*
from route  a
start with a.rowid = (select min(rowid) from route )
connect by prior a.t = a.f;
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working with a set starting point: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5672e/3

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server (2005+) it will be

```
Declare @Routes Table([from] int, [to] int, [street] varchar(17))   
INSERT INTO @Routes VALUES
(92, 91, 'Lange Poten'),
(100, 104, 'Bagijnestraat'),
(85, 79, 'Korte Poten'),
(91, 85, 'Plein'),
(79, 100, 'Bezuidenhoutseweg')

;With  Cte AS
(
    SELECT  [from]
            ,[to]
            ,[street]
    FROM    @Routes
    WHERE   [from] = 92
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.[from]
            ,r.[to]
            ,r. [street]
FROM    @Routes AS r
JOIN    Cte c
ON      c.[to] = r.[from]
)

Select * From Cte
```

[image]